# Primary key violated but no duplciates in source or target

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

JDBC Batch Insert Statement that is throwing...

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHK_INCLRNG_U.DDA_TRIAL_BAL_STG_PK) violated
```

The source of the data does not have any duplicates. The target has no data, so there can't be duplicates. Interesting thing I found is that when I run a count on the table i get the entire record count of the data. So it's throwing this immediately at the end. My primary key is defined in my create table statement as follows...

```
CONSTRAINT DDA_TRIAL_BAL_STG_PK PRIMARY KEY (FIRM_BNK_ID,ACCT_NB,BAT_PROC_DT)
```

Not sure what to do. This wasn't happening earlier and not sure what anyone on my team did to cause this. Don't believe any indexes were created on this table (i've read this may cause an issue)

What other issues would throw this error if there aren't true duplicates in the data?

Comment: The error message tells you that it is the primary key unique constraint that is being violated. If your target has no data then it won't hurt to delete the table and try inserting again, if you still get the error then you definitely have duplicates in your source data for what's inserted into the primary key columns. I suggest you double check this (and check your insert statement to make sure the right data is going into the right columns)

Comment: @AndrewSayer I don't have any duplicates. I ran a sort -u on the file and just to be safe I ran only a sort -u on the key values of the file. Record count is still the same. I have deleted the table multiple times and retried. I think it's important to point out that this is happening at the end. And not just on the last record, like after the last record is inserted. The count in the table after the exception is thrown and my app fails is the count of the file. Why would that exception be thrown after all the data has been written? All record we successful essentially.

Comment: "Don't believe any indexes were created on this table" - what do you mean? Your table has a primary key; if you did not explicitly instruct Oracle to use an existing index, then Oracle created a unique index on the PK. So, I'll ask again - what do you mean by that?

Comment: The obvious thing that comes to mind is that there's nothing wrong with the data, but there is something wrong with the insert process. Such as, for whatever reason, it is attempted more than once. That's why (maybe!) the proper rows get inserted, and it looks as if the error is thrown right AFTER all the rows were inserted. As soon as the first row is tentatively inserted AGAIN, the error is thrown.

Comment: @mathguy sorry, that probably caused confusion. I meant no index was created because i had read somewhere that additional indexes (outside of the primary key) could cause this issue. So just was clarifying that no indexes in addition to the primary key constraint were created on this table. As to your second comment, I think this may be the case. For whatever reason idk. Going to test a few things now.

Comment: If you share your Java code, some clever volunteer should be able to spot the multiple runs issue if it exists. Obviously a good idea to cut it down to a small amount of code (but make sure it’s still enough to reproduce your issue), I am also thinking that a second insert is probably likely if what you’re saying is correct.

Answer (score 1):

in Oracle you can use log errors to capture the exception and see which row is violating the constraints.

for example

```
create table t1(col1 number);

create unique index t_ix on t1(col1);

begin
 dbms_errlog.create_error_log('t1');
end;

 --in your insert statement you will have the following statement appended
 log errors reject limit unlimited;

-- The error will be captured in
select * from err$_t1;
```